# React, update individual value from button click

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to have a list where you click a button on the left and it will give you a summary of items on the right.  The state array updates and new items are added to the list but the text for the number of items won't update.  The amount only increases if I force another render or until I add a different item to the list.

[screenshot][1]:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/XW7PU.png

Is there a way to update the textview for the quantity?

```
export default function EquipmentSelect() {
    const [selectedEquipment, setSelectedEquipment] = useState([]);

    const equipmentList = [
        { name: 'item 1', id: '0111' },
        { name: 'item 3', id: '0112' },
        { name: 'item 5', id: '0113' },
        { name: 'item 6', id: '0114' },
        { name: 'item 7', id: '0115' },
        { name: 'item 8', id: '0116' },
        { name: 'item 9', id: '0116' },
        { name: 'item 10', id: '0117' },
        { name: 'item 11', id: '0118' },
        { name: 'item 12', id: '0119' },
    ]

    const handleButtonClick = (event, value) => {
        if (!handleCheck(value)) {
            setSelectedEquipment(selectedEquipment => [...selectedEquipment, { key: value.id, name: value.name, quantity: 1 }])
        }
        else {
            const selectedItemIndex = selectedEquipment.findIndex(item => item.key === value.id)
            selectedEquipment[selectedItemIndex] = {
                ...selectedEquipment[selectedItemIndex], quantity: selectedEquipment[selectedItemIndex].quantity + 1
            }
        }
    }
    function handleCheck(value) {
        return selectedEquipment.some(item => value.name === item.name);
    }

    return (
        <div class='equipmentContainer divRowFlex'>
            <div class='addEquipment'>
                <Autocomplete
                    freeSolo
                    options={equipmentList.map((option) => option.name)}
                    renderInput={(params) => <TextField {...params} label="Type to search..." />}
                />
                <List sx={{
                    width: '100%',
                    position: 'relative',
                    overflow: 'auto',
                    maxHeight: 300,
                    '& ul': { padding: 0 },
                }}>
                    {equipmentList.map((value) => (
                        <ListItem
                            key={value}
                            disableGutters
                            secondaryAction={
                                <IconButton
                                    onClick={(event) => handleButtonClick(event, value)}
                                >
                                    <MdAddCircle size='18' className='text-secondary my-auto' />
                                </IconButton>
                            }
                        >
                            <ListItemText primary={`${value.name}`} />
                        </ListItem>
                    ))}
                </List>
            </div>
            <div class='selectedEquipment divColFlex'>
                <div class='divRowFlex selectedEquipmentHeader'>
                    <h1>Selected Equipment:</h1>
                    <h1>QTY</h1>
                </div>
                <div class='selectedEquipmentItemContainer '>
                    {selectedEquipment.map(item =>
                        <div class='divRowFlex selectedEquipmentItem'>
                            <h2>{item.name}</h2>
                            <h2>{item.quantity}</h2>
                        </div>
                    )}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
selectedEquipment[selectedItemIndex] = {
                ...selectedEquipment[selectedItemIndex], quantity: selectedEquipment[selectedItemIndex].quantity + 1
            }
```

Isn't calling `setState` and therefore won't force rerender

```
setSelectedEquipment(prev=> {
  prev[selectedItemIndex] = {
                ...prev[selectedItemIndex], quantity: prev[selectedItemIndex].quantity + 1
            }
 return prev
}
```

Will do the same logic with rerender

Comment: I tried this and it doesn't seem to change anything.  I replaced the initial selectedEquipment with your alteration.

Comment: You should replace the first code block attached in my answer with the second block

Answer (score -1):

I managed to find the solution. It is due to the fact that I was never updating the state array.

```
            let newArry = [...selectedEquipment]
            const selectedItemIndex = newArry.findIndex(item => item.key === value.id)
            newArry[selectedItemIndex] = {
                ...newArry[selectedItemIndex], quantity: newArry[selectedItemIndex].quantity + 1
            }
            setSelectedEquipment(newArry)
        }
```